# How to manage the lifetime of Ogre3D objects?

Tags: c++, ogre, resource-management

I haven't found tutorials that are concerned about deleting scenenodes and entities. I assume that the scenemanager will take ownership of them when they are attached (am I right?). However, I can imagine many situations where I would like to deterministically and selectively terminate objects, for example if I were to use OGRE to display a huge open-world level, I would like to dynamically load and unload parts of the world. How can I do this while also telling the scenemanager that his pointer is no longer valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the facts that is not recommended to delete entities and scenenodes yourself, did you take a look at the [Ogre SceneManager documention](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneManager.html) ?

---

In this document you can find the following functions to remove & destroy entities:

- [void destroyEntity (Entity *ent)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneManager.html#aaec976bb28961a149c71a5eba62f40e4)

  Removes & destroys an Entity from the SceneManager.
- [void destroyEntity (const String &name)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneManager.html#a3e19d4a7d848a745a59e63fca36fa79c)

  Removes & destroys an Entity from the SceneManager by name.
- [void destroyAllEntities (void)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneManager.html#a1a77be68ccbfc90e2e1aed04340db4dc)

  Removes & destroys all Entities.

---

And you can find the following function to remove & destroy Scene Nodes:

- [void destroySceneNode (const String &name)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneManager.html#a1a77be68ccbfc90e2e1aed04340db4dc)

  Destroys a SceneNode with a given name.
- [void    destroySceneNode (SceneNode *sn)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneManager.html#aa613e5ffb08b95a90644a61ac10c9b5c)

  Destroys a SceneNode.

---

Anyway don't forget you need to detach entities from the sceneNode first to avoid problems...

- [MovableObject * detachObject (unsigned short index)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneNode.html#a4d0832b90b91afe9fd4154e12c8481a1)

  Detaches the indexed object from this scene node.
- [void detachObject (MovableObject *obj)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneNode.html#abc4846642c14ab6e3ca1a4f6296b859a)

  Detaches an object by pointer.
- [MovableObject * detachObject (const String &name)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneNode.html#af52d04c1d2aa341f7e02daeb7355372b)

  Detaches the named object from this node and returns a pointer to it.
- [void detachAllObjects (void)](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1SceneNode.html#a064b81e279b10a488ba018d1ac87abb5)

  Detaches all objects attached to this node.

---

Finally **I do really recommend you to take a look at the [Scene Manager FAQ](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ)**. This document presents the different ways to manage the scene nodes using [BSP](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ#BSP_Scene_Manager), [Octree](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ#Octree_Scene_Manager) or [Portal Connected Zone](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ#Portal_Connected_Zone_Scene_Manager_PCZSM_) etc. This is probably better way to achieve what you want to to without having to manage the scene nodes yourself.

Comment: If not managing by myself, then what is the preferred way to efficiently load and maintain very big scenes (i.e. open world-type scenes)?

Comment: [Octree scene manager](http://tinyurl.com/7yr4a4d) could probably fits your needs. The [Scene Manager FAQ](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ) (introduced at the bottom of my answer) presents you the pros and cons of each Ogre Scene Manager type.